# summarize_at for multiple variables and multiple functions with different arguments in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have 5 variables in my df, I want to summarize_at them using the following pattern for each variable:

```
min, quantile(.25), median, mean, qunatile(.75), max, sd
```

Here is my sample df, please advise how to do this:

```
df <- structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), obs_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), scroll_id = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), timestamp = c(1540202430007839232, 
1540202430009840640, 1540202430010982656, 1540202430010982656, 
1540202430011841792, 1540202430013843200, 1540202430015844608, 
1540202430017846016, 1540202430019847168, 1540202430020992512
), start_time = c(1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 
1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 
1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 
1540202430007839232), end_time = c(1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328, 
1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328, 
1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328, 
1540202430075907328, 1540202430075907328), gra_x = c(0.028428223, 
0.028428223, 0.024191462, 0.024191462, 0.024191462, 0.024191462, 
0.024191462, 0.024191462, 0.024191462, 0.008488427), gra_y = c(3.3407776, 
3.3407776, 3.329257, 3.329257, 3.329257, 3.329257, 3.329257, 
3.329257, 3.329257, 3.2995365), gra_z = c(9.220019, 9.220019, 
9.224198, 9.224198, 9.224198, 9.224198, 9.224198, 9.224198, 9.224198, 
9.234899), lin_acc_mag = c(1.87035263799625, 1.87035263799625, 
1.87035263799625, 1.46659090346921, 1.46659090346921, 1.46659090346921, 
1.46659090346921, 1.46659090346921, 1.46659090346921, 1.46659090346921
), vel_ang_unc_mag = c(0.363288181726866, 0.397720202371128, 
0.397720202371128, 0.397720202371128, 0.462731530212917, 0.493683807731099, 
0.553539962506893, 0.607457519129218, 0.629400228979264, 0.629400228979264
)), .Names = c("user_id", "obs_id", "scroll_id", "timestamp", 
"start_time", "end_time", "gra_x", "gra_y", "gra_z", "lin_acc_mag", 
"vel_ang_unc_mag"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("user_id", "obs_id", 
"scroll_id"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:9), group_sizes = 10L, biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    user_id = 1L, obs_id = 1L, scroll_id = 3L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("user_id", "obs_id", "scroll_id"
), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("user_id", "obs_id", "scroll_id")))


df %>% 
summarize_at(vars(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag), 
             funs(min, max, mean, median, sd, quantile, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)))
```

Returns an error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column `gra_x_quantile` must be
>   length 1 (a summary value), not 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working if you separate the call the `quantile` for each probs as it expects a result of length one.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~user_id, ~obs_id, ~scroll_id,          ~timestamp,         ~start_time,           ~end_time,      ~gra_x,    ~gra_y,   ~gra_z,     ~lin_acc_mag,  ~vel_ang_unc_mag,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.028428223, 3.3407776, 9.220019, 1.87035263799625, 0.363288181726866,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430009840640, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.028428223, 3.3407776, 9.220019, 1.87035263799625, 0.397720202371128,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430010982656, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.87035263799625, 0.397720202371128,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430010982656, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.397720202371128,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430011841792, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.462731530212917,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430013843200, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.493683807731099,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430015844608, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.553539962506893,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430017846016, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.607457519129218,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430019847168, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.024191462,  3.329257, 9.224198, 1.46659090346921, 0.629400228979264,
  1L,      1L,         3L, 1540202430020992512, 1540202430007839232, 1540202430075907328, 0.008488427, 3.2995365, 9.234899, 1.46659090346921, 0.629400228979264
)
df %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag), 
               funs(min, max, mean, median, sd, quantile(.,probs = c(0.25)), quantile(., probs = 0.75)))  
#> # A tibble: 1 x 30
#>   gra_x_min gra_y_min gra_z_min lin_acc_mag_min vel_ang_unc_mag~ gra_x_max
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1   0.00849      3.30      9.22            1.47            0.363    0.0284
#> # ... with 24 more variables: gra_y_max <dbl>, gra_z_max <dbl>,
#> #   lin_acc_mag_max <dbl>, vel_ang_unc_mag_max <dbl>, gra_x_mean <dbl>,
#> #   gra_y_mean <dbl>, gra_z_mean <dbl>, lin_acc_mag_mean <dbl>,
#> #   vel_ang_unc_mag_mean <dbl>, gra_x_median <dbl>, gra_y_median <dbl>,
#> #   gra_z_median <dbl>, lin_acc_mag_median <dbl>,
#> #   vel_ang_unc_mag_median <dbl>, gra_x_sd <dbl>, gra_y_sd <dbl>,
#> #   gra_z_sd <dbl>, lin_acc_mag_sd <dbl>, vel_ang_unc_mag_sd <dbl>,
#> #   gra_x_quantile <dbl>, gra_y_quantile <dbl>, gra_z_quantile <dbl>,
#> #   lin_acc_mag_quantile <dbl>, vel_ang_unc_mag_quantile <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

EDIT:

If you want lots of probabilities for quantile, you may not want to write everything by hand. Staying in the tidyverse, a solution is to use tidyeval.

1. Generate a list a function
2. Apply these functions by splicing the list

here is how to do it:

```r
# generate a vector with quantile probs you want (here 50)
quant <- seq(0, 1, 0.2)
# create a list of function, one per quantile wanted
lqfun <- map(quant, ~ partial(quantile, probs = .x, .lazy = FALSE)) %>%
  set_names(paste0("probs", quant*100))
head(lqfun, 2)
#> $probs0
#> function (...) 
#> quantile(probs = 0, ...)
#> <environment: 0x000000001cd61730>
#> 
#> $probs20
#> function (...) 
#> quantile(probs = 0.2, ...)
#> <environment: 0x000000001cd70f18>

# Apply these function in funs usint splicing. 
sum1 <- df %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag), 
               funs(min, max, mean, median, sd, !!!lqfun))  
names(sum1)
#>  [1] "gra_x_min"                "gra_y_min"               
#>  [3] "gra_z_min"                "lin_acc_mag_min"         
#>  [5] "vel_ang_unc_mag_min"      "gra_x_max"               
#>  [7] "gra_y_max"                "gra_z_max"               
#>  [9] "lin_acc_mag_max"          "vel_ang_unc_mag_max"     
#> [11] "gra_x_mean"               "gra_y_mean"              
#> [13] "gra_z_mean"               "lin_acc_mag_mean"        
#> [15] "vel_ang_unc_mag_mean"     "gra_x_median"            
#> [17] "gra_y_median"             "gra_z_median"            
#> [19] "lin_acc_mag_median"       "vel_ang_unc_mag_median"  
#> [21] "gra_x_sd"                 "gra_y_sd"                
#> [23] "gra_z_sd"                 "lin_acc_mag_sd"          
#> [25] "vel_ang_unc_mag_sd"       "gra_x_probs0"            
#> [27] "gra_y_probs0"             "gra_z_probs0"            
#> [29] "lin_acc_mag_probs0"       "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs0"  
#> [31] "gra_x_probs20"            "gra_y_probs20"           
#> [33] "gra_z_probs20"            "lin_acc_mag_probs20"     
#> [35] "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs20"  "gra_x_probs40"           
#> [37] "gra_y_probs40"            "gra_z_probs40"           
#> [39] "lin_acc_mag_probs40"      "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs40" 
#> [41] "gra_x_probs60"            "gra_y_probs60"           
#> [43] "gra_z_probs60"            "lin_acc_mag_probs60"     
#> [45] "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs60"  "gra_x_probs80"           
#> [47] "gra_y_probs80"            "gra_z_probs80"           
#> [49] "lin_acc_mag_probs80"      "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs80" 
#> [51] "gra_x_probs100"           "gra_y_probs100"          
#> [53] "gra_z_probs100"           "lin_acc_mag_probs100"    
#> [55] "vel_ang_unc_mag_probs100"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You'll have all in column here. Another solution is to work with list column. One column quantile containing a list, the result of `quantile(., probs=quant)`. Then you can unnest or manipulate list columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I will need 50 quantiles values isn't there any efficient solution, automative one?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use tidyeval for this kind of thing.

Comment: This is syntax from `rlang` that power tidyeval used in `dplyr` (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). `!!!` is for using a list of function I created as multiple argument and not a list in `funs`. The best intro I know for tidy evaluation is this webinar https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2018/tidy-eval-programming-with-dplyr-tidyr-and-ggplot2-hadley-wickham and those resources https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/
This spcific syntax can only be used in function supporting tidy evaluation, i.e tidyverse package.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with below 2 packages...

```
library(Hmisc)
describe(df[,c(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag)])

library(psych)
describe.by(df[,c(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag)])

summary(df[,c(gra_x, gra_y, gra_z, lin_acc_mag, vel_ang_unc_mag)])
```